# Unable To Access Web Method From Javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I need some help, I've been trying to implement invoking a C# method
from client side, I already got a result in a solution environment but when I try to migrate to another namespace it just does nothing.

I hope you can help me.

Maybe it could refer to something related to the configuration of my solution but I don´t know what else to do.

Here is my code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onbeforeunload = function () {
            PageMethods.ejecutar();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
          <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="True">
            </asp:ScriptManager>
        <div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

C# code:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void ejecutar()
{
    string n = "success"
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.